# Copying to Microsoft Excel with specs of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy, paste

When I copy text from another program to Excel, it does not preserve the properties of the text, such as being bold or italic. It pastes it as a plain text. Is there any way to save the text to Excel with these features, whether bold or italic?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Excel seems very limited regarding the clipboard formats that it
accepts. If the program that does the copy does it without putting
the text on the clipboard in a format that it understands, Excel
will just paste the pure text without the formatting.

Here is an example where the format is lost : Select some formatted
text in Word, copy and paste into Wordpad and see that the format
is still correct. Now select the text in Wordpad and copy-paste to Excel.
The formatting will now be lost.

A workaround that I found to keep the formatting is :

1. Paste the copied text into Word - this will keep the format
2. Select and copy the text again, but from inside Word
3. Paste the text into Excel.

Word seems to be more flexible about the formats that it accepts,
and it also copies the text and its format into the clipboard
in a format that Excel can understand.

Comment: I remember trying that before, man. But it's a long way. I will do it for hundreds, thousands of words in a very long process. That would consume my time. Thank you. Excel needs to be able to copy proper formatting too.

Comment: You need to set the source application to generate a format that Excel understands. Otherwise, you may signal the problem to Microsoft on the Feedback Hub, but we users can't change Excel.

Comment: no need. thank you.